# C# DataGridView single button to go back

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form over which I have a panel. When a button is clicked, I turn my panel to invisible and I show a DataGridView ( a table from sql ). My problem is... is there any way to put a button somewhere on my form so I can go back to the main menu ( on click, to set the panel visibility to true ).

I tried using DataGridViewButtons but it's not ok. I want just one single button, anywhere on my form, called Back that would take me back. Somehow, it won't let me place a button anywhere unless I have a panel. Is there any solution?

I can add any code if necessary, just tell me which

```
            menu.Visible = false;
            DataGridView dgw = new DataGridView();
            dgw.Parent = this;
            dgw.Location = new Point(
                    this.ClientSize.Width / 3 - dgw.Size.Width / 2,
                    this.ClientSize.Height / 4 - dgw.Size.Height / 2);
            dgw.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
            dgw.AutoSize = true;
            dgw.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(210, 121, 84);
            dgw.Text = "Login";
            dgw.Padding = new Padding(10);
            dgw.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

Comment: Did you dock the datagridview maybe? Or have some other control in place

Comment: Other option would be if ou would have locked your design view (right mouse button on the form -> lock controls)

Comment: I added the code for my datagridview and how it looks like

Comment: So you don't use the designer...?

Comment: No. I write the code myself :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is far more easy to create your form from the designer, placing a Button on the form code is as simple as creating the datagrid.

```
private void CreateButton()
{
    var button = new Button
    {
        Text = "Press me",
        Name = "SomeButtonName",
        Location = new Point(10,10),
        Size    = new Size(100,20),
        Visible =  true,
    };

    button.Click += (s, e) => this.ButtonClicked();

    this.Controls.Add(button);
}

private void ButtonClicked()
{
    // this will fire on click
}
```

You can call `this.CreateButton()' everywhere you'll like.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently my button was hidden behind the datagrid, that's why I didn't see it being created